# Can we declare variables inside a begin-end block of plpgsql function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I tried to write the simple function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_mail_settings_column() RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
    asd text := 'asd';
END $$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But it doesn't work:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "asd"
LINE 3:  asd text := 'asd';
```

But if I move it as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_mail_settings_column() RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
    asd text := 'asd';
BEGIN

END $$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

It works fine. So we can't put variable declarations into a function body can we?

Comment: All variables used in a block must be declared in the declarations section of the block.

Answer (score 14):

You can declare variables only in the DECLARE section of a block. But you can code blocks inside blocks. This is copied directly from the [PostgreSQL docs on the structure of PL/pgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-structure.html).

```
CREATE FUNCTION somefunc() RETURNS integer AS $$
<< outerblock >>
DECLARE
    quantity integer := 30;
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'Quantity here is %', quantity;  -- Prints 30
    quantity := 50;
    --
    -- Create a subblock
    --
    DECLARE
        quantity integer := 80;
    BEGIN
        RAISE NOTICE 'Quantity here is %', quantity;  -- Prints 80
        RAISE NOTICE 'Outer quantity here is %', outerblock.quantity;  -- Prints 50
    END;

    RAISE NOTICE 'Quantity here is %', quantity;  -- Prints 50

    RETURN quantity;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```